# How to go from Radon–Nikodym derivative to classical derivative in change of variables formula of p.d.f.?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, radon-nikodym

Let $X$ be an absolutely continuous real-valued random variable whose  distribution is $\mu_X$ and whose p.d.f. is $p_X$. Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable such that $f'(t)>0$ for all $t\in \mathbb R$. This implies $f$ is strictly increasing. Let $Y := f(X)$. Clearly, the distribution $\mu_Y$ of $Y$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lebesgue measure $\lambda$. Let $F_Y,p_Y$ be the c.d.f. and p.d.f. of $Y$ respectively.

Clearly, $\mu_Y$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu_X$. According to this Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Properties),
$$
p_Y := \frac{\mathrm d  \mu_Y}{\mathrm d  \lambda} = \frac{\mathrm d  \mu_Y}{\mathrm d  \mu_X} \frac{\mathrm d  \mu_X}{\mathrm d  \lambda}.
$$

Here $\frac{\mathrm d  \mu_Y}{\mathrm d  \mu_X}$ is the Radon–Nikodym derivative of $\mu_Y$ w.r.t. $\mu_X$. Similarly, $\frac{\mathrm d  \mu_X}{\mathrm d  \lambda}$ is the Radon–Nikodym derivative of $\mu_X$ w.r.t. $\lambda$. At page $14$ of this lecture [note](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1920.pdf), the author mentioned that

> $$
> p_Y (t) = \frac{\mathrm d F_Y (t)}{\mathrm d t} = \frac{\mathrm d  F_X (f^{-1} (t))}{\mathrm d  t} \frac{\mathrm d  f^{-1} (t)}{\mathrm d t} =\frac{p_X (f^{-1} (t))}{f'(f^{-1} (t))}.
> $$

Clearly, the map $F_\lambda:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, t \mapsto t$ is the corresponding c.d.f. of $\lambda$. Obviously, the p.d.f. of $\lambda$ is $p_\lambda:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, t \mapsto 1$. It seems to me the author meant by $\frac{\mathrm d  F_X (f^{-1} (t))}{\mathrm d  t}$ the value of $p_X :=\frac{\mathrm d  \mu_X}{\mathrm d  \lambda}$ at $f^{-1} (t)$, i.e.,
$$
\frac{\mathrm d  F_X (f^{-1} (t))}{\mathrm d  t} = \frac{\mathrm d  \mu_X}{\mathrm d  \lambda} (f^{-1} (t)) =p_X (f^{-1} (t)).
$$

Could you elaborate on how to transfer from the Radon–Nikodym derivative $\frac{\mathrm d  \mu_Y}{\mathrm d  \mu_X}$ to the classical derivative $\frac{\mathrm d  f^{-1} (t)}{\mathrm d t}$, i.e.,
$$
\frac{\mathrm d  \mu_Y}{\mathrm d  \mu_X} (t) = \frac{\mathrm d  f^{-1}}{\mathrm d t} (t)?
$$

Comment: Hint: the distribution of $Y=f(X)$ is by definition $\mu_Y=\mu_X\circ f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We proved in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540011/the-absolute-continuity-of-push-forward-measure) thread that $\mu_Y$ is indeed absolutely continuous (a.c.) w.r.t. $\lambda$.

> [Lemma:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Relation_between_the_two_notions_of_absolute_continuity) If a finite Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ is a.c. w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ then $\frac{\mathrm d  \mu}{\mathrm d  \lambda} = F'$ a.e. where $F (x) := \mu((\infty, x])$.

By **Lemma**, we have
$$
\frac{\mathrm d  \mu_Y}{\mathrm d  \lambda} (t) = (F_Y)'(t) = (F_X \circ f^{-1}) ' (t) \quad \text{for a.e. } t \in \mathbb R.
$$

Also by the **Lemma**, we have $(F_X)' = p_X$ a.e. The claim then follows by applying the chain rule.