# The absolute continuity of push-forward measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, derivatives, probability-distributions, lebesgue-measure

Let $X$ be a real-valued random variable on $\mathbb R$, and $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ differentiable such that $f'(x)>0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Let $Y := f(X)$. Let $\mu_X, \mu_Y$ be the distributions of $X, Y$ respectively. Then $\mu_Y = f_{\sharp} \mu_X$. Let $F_X, F_Y$ be the c.d.f. of $X, Y$ respectively. At page $14$ of this lecture [note](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1920.pdf), the author said that

> **Theorem:** If $\mu_X$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. Lesbesgue measure $\lambda$, then so is $\mu_Y$

**My attempt:** Clearly, we have $F_Y (t) = F_X \circ f^{-1} (t)$. Let $A$ be a Borel set such that $\lambda(A) = 0$. Because $\mu_X \ll \lambda$, we get $\mu_X (A) =0$. We have $\mu_Y (A) = \mu_X(f^{-1} (A))$. It suffices to prove $f^{-1} (A)$ is a $\lambda$-null set.

Could you shed some light on how to finish the proof?

---

**Update:** I have found a related result [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128477/preimage-of-zero-measure-sets). However, it requires $f$ to be **continuously** differentiable, i.e., if $f\in C^1$ and $\{f' = 0\}$ is $\lambda$-null then $f^{-1} (A)$ is also $\lambda$-null.

Comment: I feel like Baire's category theorem could be somehow useful here...

Comment: @Masacroso In the [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403008/is-there-an-increasing-function-on-a-b-which-is-differentiable-but-not-abs) you gave, the function is differentiable everywhere, while in our case $F_X$ is differentiable *almost* everywhere. Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540413/the-composition-of-a-differentiable-function-with-an-absolutely-continuous-funct) for my failed attempt to prove that $F_Y = F_X \circ f^{-1}$ is absolutely continuous.

Comment: @Masacroso I could not see how Lemma 7.20 in that book helps us. Could you elaborate more? Maybe Theorem 7.21 is relevant, but the function $F$ in that theorem is assumed to be absolutely continuous.

Comment: @Masacroso The composition $a \circ b$ of 2 absolutely continuous (a.c.) functions $a,b$ [is not](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2406796/composition-of-absolutely-continuous-function-on-mathbbr) necessarily a.c. However, if in addition $b$ is (not necessarily strictly) monotone, then $a \circ b$ is a.c. Could you confirm if my understanding is correct?

Comment: @Akira I dont know. My reasoning was not correct before, sorry I didn't paid enough attention to this question. I would try to come with a definitive answer (I deleted my previous comments as they seems wrong)

Comment: @Masacroso I strongly feel that your reasoning is correct :) As I mentioned in my previous comment, $a=F_X$ and $b=f^{-1}$. Because $b$ is monotone, it sends non-overlapping intervals to non-overlapping intervals, which allows us to use the absolute continuity of $a$.

Comment: @Masacroso Please see below my answer based on your idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I formulate @Masacroso's idea as follows. First, we need 3 lemmas.

- [Lemma 1:](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/403008/is-there-an-increasing-function-on-a-b-which-is-differentiable-but-not-abs) If $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is monotone and differentiable, then $g$ is [absolutely continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4100439/368425) (a.c.).
- [Lemma 2:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4540413/the-composition-f-circ-f-of-absolutely-continuous-functions-f-f-with-f-b) Let $F:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ and $g:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be both a.c. where $g$ is (not necessarily strictly) monotone. Then $F \circ f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a.c.
- [Lemma 3:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Relation_between_the_two_notions_of_absolute_continuity) A finite measure $\mu$ on Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$ is a.c. w.r.t. Lebesgue measure if and only if the associated function $F(x) := \mu((-\infty, x])$ is a.c.

Clearly, $f^{-1}$ is monotone, and differentiable by inverse function theorem, then $f^{-1}$ is a.c. by **Lemma 1**. By **Lemma 3**, $F_X$ is a.c. By **Lemma 2**, $F_Y = F_X \circ f^{-1}$ is a.c. Then $\mu_Y$ is a.c. by **Lemma 3**.

---

**Update:** I use the following version of inverse function theorem (IFT) (at  page 306 of Amann's *Analysis I*), i.e.,

> Let $X$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R}\}, f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$, and $Y:=f(X)$. Let $f$ be injective and consider the inverse $f^{-1}: Y \rightarrow X$ of $f$. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable at $a \in X$, and $f^{-1}$ is continuous at $b:=f(a) \in Y$. Then $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $b$ if and only if $f^{\prime}(a) \neq 0$. In this case, $\left(f^{-1}\right)^{\prime}(b)=1 / f^{\prime}(a)$.

To use IFT we need to prove that $f^{-1}$ is continuous. However, this follows from [invariance of domain theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain).